# How to reopen a dialog box in PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm trying to use a dialog box in order to report an error to the user. It seems to be working if there is one error although when there are multiple it doesn't reopen when closed with the next error and instead crashes.

```
def errordialog(self, errormessage):
    self.errordialog = QMessageBox()
    self.errordialog.addButton("OK", 0)
    self.errordialog.setText(errormessage)
    self.errordialog.exec()
```

And this is the main program

```
def validate_data(data, regex):
    if re.match(regex, data, re.VERBOSE):
        error = False
    else:
        errormessage = "ERROR"
        print("0")
        self.errordialog(errormessage)
        print("1")
        self.errordialog.accept() # I added this in while trying to solve the issue
        print("2")
        error = True
    return error

data = supplierid
regex = "[A-Z]$"
error = validate_data(data, regex)
print("3")
data = suppliername
regex = ".(1,50)$"
error = validate_data(data, regex)
print("4")
```

It prints 0,1,2,3,0 and then crashes
the error message is `object QMessageBox is not callable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling this line of code `self.errordialog(errormessage)`, you go into the errordialog function. However, inside the errordialog function, you have redefined `self.errordialog` so that it is of class QMessageBox instead of class function, so when it goes through the validation the second time, you attempt to call the QMessageBox, which does not work.

Simply changing the function or variable names will solve this problem.